# Multiprocessing Freezing with Scipy Optimise

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing, scipy-optimize

EDIT: The error does not lie with multiprocessing but rather with another library. I would close the question but @Lukasz Tracewski's point of using joblib may help someone else.

I've got an issue with a task I'm trying to parallelise on windows.

It seems to work for a while then suddenly halts on a particular instance (I can tell as I get the code to print which iteration it's on). I've noticed in the task manager that the CPU usage, which such be about 50%, is minimal for the Python processes. When I then do a keyboard interrupt on the cmd prompt, this suddenly shoots forward a number of instances and the activity goes back up for a short while, only to go back down again.

I've included the bits of my code which I think are relevant. I know it can work (I don't think it's stuck on a problem) and there seems to be a degree of randomness as to when it does freeze.

I'm using the COBYLA solver with `max_iter` set. I'm not sure if it is relevant, but when I tried to use BFGS, I got a freezing problem.

```
def get_optimal_angles(G,p,coeff,objective_function,initial_gamma_range,initial_beta_range,seed):
    '''
    This performs the classical-quantum interchange, improving the values of beta and gamma by reducing the value of
    < beta, gamma | C | beta, gamma >. Returns the best angles found and the objective value this refers to. Bounds on the minimiser are set as the starting points
    '''
    initial_starting_points = random_intial_values((np.array(initial_gamma_range)),(np.array(initial_beta_range)),p,seed)

    optimiser_function =  minimize(objective_function, initial_starting_points, method='COBYLA', options={'maxiter':1500})
    best_angles = optimiser_function.x
    objective_value = optimiser_function.fun
    return best_angles,objective_value



def find_best_angles_for_graph_6(graph_seed):
    print("6:On graph",graph_seed)
    #graph = gp.unweighted_erdos_graph(10,0.4,graph_seed)
    graph = gp.unweighted_erdos_graph(6,0.4,graph_seed)
    graph_coefficients = quantum_operator_z_coefficients(graph,'Yo')
    exact_energy =get_exact_energy(graph)
    angle_starting_seed = np.arange(1,number_of_angle_points,1)

    objective_function= get_black_box_objective_sv(graph,p,graph_coefficients)
    list_of_results = []
    for angle_seed in angle_starting_seed:
        print("On Angle Seed",angle_seed)
        best_angles_for_seed, best_objective_value_for_seed = get_optimal_angles(graph,p,graph_coefficients,objective_function,[0,np.pi],[0,np.pi],angle_seed)
        success_prob = calculate_energy_success_prob(graph,p,exact_energy, graph_coefficients,best_angles_for_seed,angle_seed)
        angle_seed_data_list = [angle_seed,best_objective_value_for_seed,success_prob,best_angles_for_seed]
        list_of_results.append(angle_seed_data_list)

    list_of_best =  get_best_results(list_of_results)

    full_results = [graph_seed,exact_energy,list_of_best,list_of_results]

    return full_results



import multiprocessing as mp

def main():
    physical_cores = 5
    pool = mp.Pool(physical_cores)




    list_of_results_every_graph_6 = []
    list_of_all_graph_results_6 = pool.map(find_best_angles_for_graph_6,range(1,number_of_graphs+1))
    print(list_of_all_graph_results_6)
    file_name_6 = 'unweighted_erdos_graph_N_6_p_8.pkl'
    pickle_6 = open((file_name_6),'wb')
    pickle.dump(list_of_all_graph_results_6, pickle_6)
    pickle_6.close()

    list_of_results_every_graph_10 = []
    list_of_all_graph_results_10 = pool.map(find_best_angles_for_graph_10,range(1,number_of_graphs+1))
    print(list_of_all_graph_results_10)
    file_name_10 = 'unweighted_erdos_graph_N_9_p_8.pkl'
    pickle_10 = open((file_name_10),'wb')
    pickle.dump(list_of_all_graph_results_10, pickle_10)
    pickle_10.close()


    







if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT: Here is the full code as a Jupyter notebook. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6xb7setjsn1c1o3/AAANfH7mEmhuuf9cxh5QWsRQa?dl=0

Comment: Can you try with [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html), specifically a combination of `Parallel` and `delayed`? Reason I am asking is that `multiprocessing` does not handle well situations where non-Python code is called. It can lead to oversubsription or a lock. You might be running into the latter.

Comment: I will have a look ! Does this create processes, not threads?

Comment: Both are possible, it goes with processes by default. When you test it, try in the backend both `loky` and `multiprocessing`. Modifying the code should be simple, but if you hit a problem, shout.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. It seems to have the same problem though, just mysteriously dropping to 0% CPU usage even though the task isn't complete.

Comment: Does it complete without multiprocessing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Yes it does. The problem is more apparent when I try to use the COBYLA minimiser on a problem with ~8 variables on Windows; it seems to work fine on smaller instances and there seems to be a degree of randomness when it does flare up ! Mac OS seems to behave well.

Comment: Apologies I was wrong in my last comment. It does freeze when running on a single process indicating it is not joblib going wrong, it just only became apparent with more things running  ! Thanks for your  help regardless.

Comment: Good to know, it was really puzzling otherwise. Good luck!